# Books/sources on inner workings of JavaScript

Tags: javascript

When I started studying C++ a couple of years ago, a lot of the books and texts I read did a very thorough job of explaining, how the code written would translate into concrete operations in the hardware (like dynamically memory allocation, pointer arithmetics etc.). I found those explanations extremely helpful in order to fully understand the language.

Now I am studying JavaScript and learning about the whole functional programming paradigm, with functions as first class objects and so on. I have read a lot of texts and books about how to use JavaScript, but I have yet to come across a source, that explains the low-level inner workings of the language (like how a function is represented in memory, what excactly happens when a function is called with .apply() and a new context is provided etc.).

I guess you could say, that what I am looking for is the knowledge needed to write a JS compiler/VM..?

Does anyone know where to find books or text, that goes into the very low level details of the language?

Comment: Such details vary from runtime to runtime.

Comment: Implementation is implementation dependent.

Comment: http://channel9.msdn.com/Events/Build/2012/4-000

Comment: @SLaks Thanks for posting the video, that looks very interesting.

Comment: @Pointy Ok thanks, I did not know that. Does it vary to a degree, that makes an overall understanding meaningless to talk about?

Comment: @acrmuui I suspect there are a lot of similarities, but the very nature of the beast is that the language semantics are all that matter, unlike with C and C++, where machine implementation is important to know.